# Filtering Context.GetTable<T> with BaseClass Virtual Property

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql, base-class

We have a pretty extensive LINQ-to-SQL mapping with a back-end database containing around 150 tables.  Almost all of the tables have a common property called `CompanyCode` which functions as a sort of partition across all of the tables.

I'm currently implementing a validation tool that makes use of `context.GetTable<T>` to retrieve records for a specific entity type.  I want to filter by `CompanyCode`, but generically, e.g.:

```
context.GetTable<T>().Where(t => t.CompanyCode == "1234").ToList();
```

Since, we already have a custom abstract base class called `CPSQLEntityBase`, my thought was to add a custom virtual property `CompanyCode` that would be overridden in the LINQ classes as explained in [**this article**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2007/11/09/linq-to-sql-how-to-2-base-class-for-all-entities.aspx):

```
public abstract class CPSQLEntityBase
{
    public virtual string CompanyCode { get; set; }
}
```

I am using a custom script that uses `SqlMetal` to dynamically generate our DataContext class.  So it was trivial to add a command to find/replace all instances of `public string CompanyCode` with `public override string CompanyCode` so they would override the virtual property in the base class.  Here is what one of them looks like for example:

```
public partial class Employee : CPSQLEntityBase, INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_CompanyCode", DbType="VarChar(4) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=124)]
    public override string CompanyCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CompanyCode;
        }
        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Putting it all together, I wrote a little test script in LINQPad that should be able to request `Employee` entities using the generic method, but filtering by `CompanyCode`.  Here is my sample script:

```
void Main()
{
    ...
    Test<Employee>(context);
}

public void Test<T>(MyDataContext context)
    where T : CPSQLEntityBase
{
    var result = context.GetTable<T>().Where(t => t.CompanyCode == "1234").ToList();
}
```

However, when I execute the code above, I get an exception:

> Class member CPSQLEntityBase.CompanyCode is unmapped.

Has something changed since that Blog article was written?  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need to override it? Can't the property reside fully in the base class?

Comment: @usr: That's what I tried first, and it gives the same error message.  I also tried adding a `[Column]` Attribute directly to the base class property, and I get `Bad Storage property` exception, presumably because `CPSQLEntityBase` itself is not mapped to any entity in the SQL backend.

Comment: I found a duplicate that seems to answer my own question :) [**LINQ to SQL - mapping exception when using abstract base classes**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021274/linq-to-sql-mapping-exception-when-using-abstract-base-classes).  Looks like it may be a "bug" with a workaround.